# xpath works in browser devtools but selenium cannot find element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, checkbox

steps: after login to `techfetch.com`, and click `select all` checkbox and click `Multiple Quick Apply` button.

Then: trying to check the "Attach Covering Letter" checkbox. I could find element in browser using `//*[@id="chkCL"]` xpath. But javascript nodejs script is not able to find element.

```js
// url https://www.techfetch.com/js/js_applyemail.aspx?quickapply=true

let attachCoverCheckBox = await driver.findElement(By.xpath('//*[@id="chkCL"]'))
```

```
Process exited with code 1
Uncaught NoSuchElementError NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: //*[@id="chkCL"]
    at throwDecodedError (file:///C:/work/selenium/apply-jobs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:524:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (file:///C:/work/selenium/apply-jobs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:601:13)
    at execute (file:///C:/work/selenium/apply-jobs/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:529:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'
```

[browser dev tools xpath and `::before` pesudo tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKkYC.png)

trying to click "Attach Covering letter" checkbox on the quick apply screen of techfetch.com website. I am new to Selenium and This is my second selenium script. So, Please provide as much information you can.

Comment: You should probably be using Puppeteer with node, nobody really answers node + selenium questions here because it's not popular.

Comment: Thank you @pguardiario for the suggestion. It's more easy and stable to use puppeteer.

Answer (score -1):

please try getWindowHandle(), looks like attachCoverCheckBox element is not in the same window